# Custom validation for plugin settings

Tags: plugin-development, settings

As a follow-up to [this](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/how-to-use-plugin-settings) thread, I would like to know how to create custom validation rules for plugin settings, or at least how to return field errors to the plugin settings view. I currently have:

```
<?php namespace Craft;

class SamplePlugin extends BasePlugin {

    function getName() { ... }
    function getVersion() { ... }
    function getDeveloper() { ... }
    function getDeveloperUrl() { ... }

    public function getSettingsHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('sample/settings', [
            'settings' => $this->getSettings()
        ]);
    }

    public function prepSettings($settings)
    {
        // I'm currently doing my 'custom' validation here. But if
        // there's an error, how do I display errors on the settings page?

        return $settings;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        // Tried this, but since SamplePlugin isn't a Model, it does nothing.
    }

    protected function defineSettings()
    {
        return [
            'mySetting' => [
                AttributeType::String,
                'required' => true,
                // Can custom validation rules be set here?
            ]
        ];
    }

}
```

Comment: Duh. `$this->settings` _is_ the plugin settings model. That get's me going in the right direction.

Comment: Already asked/answered in this [thread](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/how-can-i-add-custom-validation-rules-to-my-plugin-settings).

Comment: So, you're all set, then? Can we mark this one as a duplicate?

Comment: It is a duplicate question, however, the gist provided on the other post didn't work. I'm not sure if it's outdated or what. What I provided below is what actually worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution provided [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10162/how-can-i-add-custom-validation-rules-to-my-plugin-settings) actually required some adjustments. Here is what ended up working:

In `craft/plugins/sample/SamplePlugin.php`:

```
<?php namespace Craft;

class SamplePlugin extends BasePlugin {

    function getName() { ... }
    function getVersion() { ... }
    function getDeveloper() { ... }
    function getDeveloperUrl() { ... }

    public function getSettingsHtml()
    {
        return craft()->templates->render('sample/settings', [
            'settings' => $this->getSettings()
        ]);
    }

    protected function getSettingsModel()
    {
        return new Sample_SettingsModel();
    }

}
```

In `craft/plugins/sample/models/Sample_SettingsModel.php`:

```
<?php namespace Craft;

class Sample_SettingsModel extends BaseModel {

    protected function defineAttributes()
    {
        return [
            'mySetting' => [
                AttributeType::String,
                'required' => true
            ]
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        $rules[] = ['mySetting', 'validateMySetting'];

        return $rules;
    }

    public function validateMySetting($attribute)
    {
        $value = $this->$attribute;

        if ( /* validation condition */) {
            $message = Craft::t("Error message");
            $this->addError($attribute, $message);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - this worked for me, while the other thread you linked to didn't. A difference between Plugin/BasePlugin and Model/BaseModel I think.