# Plugin settings multiline input field

Tags: plugin-development, templating

I created a plugin settings page following the example shown [here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/5067/how-to-use-plugin-settings) but my entries need to include multilines (they are email bodies). My Twig template for the settings page is like this:

```
{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}

{{ forms.textField({
    label: "Submitted Subject"|t,
    id: 'submittedSubject',
    name: 'submittedSubject',
    instructions: "Input your setting"|t,
    value: settings.submittedSubject,
    errors: settings.getErrors('submittedSubject'),
    })
}}
```

(this field is repeated 6 times).
I tried using textAreas instead of textFields, but it doesn't have the same options and I don't think it works (doesn't have a value field). Also it doesn't help that there's barely any documentation for this. Is there a way for me to have multiline text inside the text field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, the template loaded by the macro can be found in `craft/app/templates/_includes/forms/textarea.html`. It does have a `value` attribute, and a few others, for example:

```
{{ forms.textareaField({
    label:         "Submitted Subject"|t,
    id:            'submittedSubject',
    name:          'submittedSubject',
    instructions:  "Input your setting"|t,
    value:         settings.submittedSubject,
    rows:          4,
    cols:          50,
    errors:        settings.getErrors('submittedSubject'),
    maxlength:     250,
    showCharsLeft: true,
    autofocus:     settings.hasErrors('submittedSubject'),
}) }}
```

All the form macros are defined in `craft/app/templates/_includes/forms.html`.

Comment: the reason why i didn't see the value attribute and the other ones was because i was actually using textArea instead of textareaField... this works wonders though, just as i wanted it to be.